# jQuery mobile blocks jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I added 3 files to my HTML code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Without jQuery mobile my *main.js* script works properly but when included jquery mobile file script doesn't work. There is way to deal with this?

Have jQuery mobile and jQuery (basic) some conflicts? (I'm concerned about js only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your main javascript `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` only after all his dependencies so:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

If the issue persist try to use [$.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
</script>
```